# getInstalledRelatedApps is empty

Tags: javascript, android, web

I am trying to get `getInstalledRelatedApps` [documents](https://web.dev/get-installed-related-apps/) but it always return empty as `[]`.

**Code**

```
$(function () {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        if ("getInstalledRelatedApps" in navigator) {
            navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps().then((relatedApps) => {
                relatedApps.forEach((app) => {
                    console.log('platform:', app.platform);
                    console.log('url:', app.url);
                    console.log('id:', app.id);
                    // This field is provided by the UA.
                    console.log('version:', app.version);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sadly, as of May 2022, I'm not sure that `getInstalledRelatedApps()` is supported on OSX https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1114966